# jqgrid "Load more.." instead of pagination

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid and I have an issue now.I use default pagination with jqgrid but I need to use "Load more.." button in bottom of jqgrid and append data from server(php) using ajax.I am not able to find similar implementation in jqgrid documentation.What is the best approach I need to follow ?